# Regex matching exactly 3 or exactly 7 characters

Tags: regex

I'd like to match strings that are have exactly 3 characters or exactly 7 characters before a `*` (examples follow):

```
ABC*THIS SHOULD MATCH
ABCDEFG*THIS SHOULD MATCH TOO

ABCD*THIS SHOULD NOT MATCH
```

The following regex matches any number of characters between 3 and 7, but I don't want that:

```
/^\w{3,7}\*(.*)/
```

Comment: If interested in full matches: `^(?:[^*]{3}|[^*]{7})\*.*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match either 3 or 7 characters, you could first match 3 characters and optionally 4 more;

`^[^*]{3}(?:[^*]{4})?\*(.*)`

`[^*]{3}` matches 3 characters that aren't an asterisk

`(?:[^*]{4})?` optionally matches 4 characters that are not an asterisk. `?:` makes it a non capturing group since you're not interested in the content.

[Regex101 to test with](https://regex101.com/r/Pgo839/1).